# How can I move my character including all its content from one world (save) to another world (save)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since I'm playing with about 100+ mods and in singleplayer survival, I want to simulate Multiverse from Bukkit in my singleplayer mode this way.

I want to create multiple saves and only transfer the character and its current content to the new world/save, and after a while back to my original world.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Totally possible sans-mods with InvEdit I think...not sure it'll play well with your mods though

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, but not easily.

I'll assume your Minecraft name is "NoCanDo" for convenience. You can copy the `NoCanDo.dat` file from the `players` folder inside a save to another save. This file stores all your inventory, experience, etc. You also need to copy all of the 'Level.dat' files, found in the world save.

That's the easy part. The problem is that it *also* stores your location and respawn (bed) location, which may be underground or a hundred blocks in the air in the world you just copied it into, and will likely result in immediate death if it's just copied straight across.

You can fix that by hand, and this is where the "not easily" part comes in. Using a tool like [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) you can open a save and view the contents of a player's `.dat` file and modify the data directly. Once you've copied the `.dat` over, open the destination save in NBTExplorer and navigate to `[savename]/players/NoCanDo.dat/Pos` and set the three numbers under `Pos` to a safe location in your new world. I ususally choose the spawn point, since that's reliably safe and I can find the exact coordinates with NBTExplorer inside the `level.dat` of the save. The numbers under `Pos` aren't labeled, so remember that they go in X, Y, Z order from top to bottom.

You can similarly change your respawn location by editing the `SpawnX`, `SpawnY`, and `SpawnZ` entries in a players `.dat` file, or you can skip that fiddling and just sleep in a bed as soon as you can.

As always, make backups!

Comment: Or more simply, use MCEdit to move player location.

Comment: @Alvin MCEdit does not always play nice with worlds that contain mod blocks. I've had entire forests turn into pistons doing that. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: player.dat DOES NOT save the inventory
if you look in NBTexplorer, the players inventory actually comes into level.dat under data/player/inventory this is for 1.5.4

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the same thing and nothing was working for me. The solution SevenSidedDie gave kind of work, but has too much things to do. I was able to do it with just 2 steps.

Considering I'm running Minecraft version 1.11, and did this also using [NBTExplorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer), this is what I did:

1. Move the player inventory from the folder `playerdata` [image: playerdata location]
2. Move the player inventory located on the `level.dat` [image: level.dat location]
3. Save the changes

Note that I'm not moving the whole `level.dat` file. If you do this, you are also moving the world data, which is going to break the world.

That's it. You don't need to worry about anything else, e.g. player location, spawn point, etc.. This is going to change just the inventory.

Comment: Just curious, what is the difference between the player inventory in `playerdata` and the player inventory in `level.dat`? Would something break if you only moved one?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to transfer your player to another world involves using iChun's Sync mod and MCedit.

First of all back up your worlds. You should always do this before tinkering with the game's files in any substantial way, anyway.

In the world are transferring from, make a clone with a Shell Constructor and pig(s) on treadmill(s), make a Shell Storage (don't forget to activate it with the lever) and use it to switch from your old player (henceforth we'll call him transferPlayer) to your new clone. Pause the game and click "Save and Quit to Title".

Open the world you were just playing in MCedit and then find the Shell Storage with transferPlayer in it and export it as a schematic (include a few extra layers of blocks on the side the lever is on, as the lever must be included with the shell storage).

Open the target world to which you want to transfer transferPlayer in MCEdit and place the Shell storage containing him. Save and close the world. Exit MCEdit

In the world where you placed shell storage in the previous step, create another Shell storage and switch from the old player from that world to transferPlayer. With that, your player should have been successfully transferred.

Lastly, turn off the power to kill the original player from this world. This way, when you die, you respawn and don't go back to original player for this world.

Done with MCEdit-0.1.7.1 and Sync 2.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

The newer MCEdit versions play a lot more nicely with modpacks. I've imported custom structures into heavily modded worlds without messing up any chunks at all and moved modded structures between worlds (of the same mod) successfully.

The only bugs I've experienced with MCEdit (as of writing) is that it does not always handle block rotation properly, for example chests may face backwards or multiblock structures that are sensitive to directionality (like custom/modded beds, double-wide tables, etc) may need to be broken and re-placed or else they may have buggy behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but people still come through here so some clarification for the new way to do this.

As mentioned in a comment to an answer, the easiest way to do this now is to set the character to creative (if possible) then copy over level.dat to the new world (overwriting the old level.dat).
Furthermore you can transfer a world but not its mod info over via copying over the region folder, this is useful if a mod like abyssalcraft has tried to generate a structure but corrupted while trying to do so or if any mods world data has corrupted somehow causing strange CtD's (Crash to Desktops). It's also useful if you dont want to risk spawning in the sky/underground while having the character in survival mode.

Answer (score -2):

As an attribution to other answers you could also after coping the player files over instead of editing all the players files with nbt explorer you could just put a repeat command block in the world that tps any player to a save location. That would be much easier and quicker then editing all the data by yourself.