# Change sea level in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any mod or server plugin that changes the map generation in Minecraft to adjust sea level?

Basically I am looking for something that will let you customize what you want the sea level to be and then it changes the water to be at that level. However it should also take into account things such as trees and beaches. So if where a tree would normally generate is now underwater then the tree would no longer be there, additionally it would make beaches at the new water level rather than at the 63 block height.

Comment: This kind of request for mods is considered off-topic for the same reasons that game buying advice questions are off-topic.  [See here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1486/1351) for some justification.

Comment: This isn't shopping, this is existence, I want to know if such a thing even exists, not what the best one is.

Comment: Then please show your research and ask an objective question based on it.  If you know a mod exists already, then ask about the specific mod, not "Is there any mod..."

Comment: @LagAttack It *probably* and *to my knowledge* doesn't exist. In fact, from what I can tell it would take *a lot of effort* to create a mod with which to change the sealevel in runtime without having nasty transition chunks or other problems (caves with lower water line, etc.). Simply put: This is not a site to have us look for a mod (there are many more resources to do that, and we just can't give reasonably scoped answers to it), and it isn't a site to request a mod either.

Comment: @FEichinger I don't think it would take much effort it could be a simple mod that during terrain generation checks for air blocks beneath a certain level and then if they exist it converts them to water, then the terrain generator could add in caves, dungeons, etc. like normal in order to make them be empty like usual. Change the forest generation, or even remove it completely, and that's pretty much it.

And you were talking about websites that are better suited for this kind of question, can you link me to any of these websites?

Comment: @MBraedley Objective question: Does such a mod exist, and if it does what is it called? That's fairly objective
Although questions like this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112513/how-can-i-move-my-character-including-all-its-content-from-one-world-save-to-a
Ask if there is a way to do something that normally isn't possible in Minecraft, I don't see how this is much different.

Comment: You're in luck! This has already been asked, so you can get instant answers. Head on over to that duplicate question and look over the answers.

Comment: Note that mod recommendation questions are not off-topic per se. See these [meta] posts for more info: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-am-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That question poses more of a work around for what I'm going for rather than an actual solution. Instead of just water everywhere I was hoping for the ocean to be up to 100 blocks deep at some points, but simply making everything ocean biome doesn't change how deep it is. The Phoenix Terrain Mod that was also linked there is a dead project so that won't work either. Although still, thanks for the link, and if I can't find anything else I will just use that solution.

Comment: @LagAttack It's still a duplicate question, which we don't do. Answers should go there instead of asking a new question. To get it some fresh attention I've put a bounty on it and updated the body to match its title better. Let's see if that doesn't get some new answers. (If you keep searching and find something within the 1-week bounty period, make it an answer and you might get the rep!)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks for the help, sorry for the other off topic questions, I didn't really read the FAQ stuff before I posted them.